# get access to child objects in react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm pulling data from an API which returns the data like this

```
[
   {
      "id":466,
      "createdDate":"2019-04-18 13:22:34",
      "updatedDate":null,
      "isAdmin":false,
      "createGroupRequestsCount":0,
      "createdGroupsCount":0,
      "postsCount":0,
      "community":{
         "id":7,
         "createdDate":"2019-04-18 13:14:34",
         "avatar":"",
         "name":"FAX International School Community",
         "description":"",
         "referenceId":6,
         "referenceName":"Fax International School",
         "referenceAlias":"FIS",
         "createGroupRequestsCount":0,
         "groupsCount":0,
         "postsCount":0
      },
      "member":{
         "id":501,
         "firstname":"Jack",
         "lastname":"Manson",
         "othernames":null,
         "createdDate":"2019-04-18 13:21:49",
         "updatedDate":null,
         "isEmployee":false,
         "email":"ernest.agyekum@minex360.com",
         "avatar":null,
         "primaryContact":"+233244908666",
         "referenceId":1112,
         "postsCount":0
      }
   }
]
```

I pull the data with the below script, which returns the data with child objects as well

```
componentDidMount = async () => {
const communities = await API.getUserCommunityInfo(userId,schoolId);
const groups = await API.getGroups(communityMemberId);
console.log(communities)

}
```

When I try to access the child object `member` with `console.log(communities.member[0].id)` I get an error message `cannot read property of 0 undefined`

Any help on how to retrieve the child objects?

Comment: What print the property "groups"?

Comment: shouldn't it just be `communities[0].member.id` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting the error because `member` is not a direct child of `communities`

`communities` is an `Array` of `Objects`, so to access to the first member you should do `communities[0].member.id`.